# How to start all applications deployed in tomcat Concurrently

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, tomcat7, war

Is there any config in tomcat where in I can mention that start all application at same time when tomcat restarts. This is to avoid latency during tomcat restarts.

Answer (score 8):

The best you can do is configure a suitably large `startStopThreads` setting for the `<Host .../>` element in `server.xml` so each `Context` starts in a parallel thread.

How successful this is will depend on how many cores you have on your system compared to the number of web applications and the relative start times of each web application.

Full details of the `startStopThreads` are available in the [Tomcat Documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/host.html).

Comment: Are there any reasons to avoid using this? Any errors that can be caused by loading two or more applications simultaneously?

Comment: No reason to avoid this. No Tomcat errors can be triggered. You might see app errors if the apps make assumptions about start order (which they shouldn't)

Comment: Seems to work. I split up total CPUs amongst Hosts (ie. allocate 2 threads per hosts due to 4 CPUs for better results). I got about 30% boost by doing it this way.

Answer (score 1):

They all start automatically, I'm not sure what else you need.

AFAIK they're started sequentially, one after the other - probably this is what you're aiming at. I'm not aware of a multi-threaded concurrent start, but even if this would be the case, they'd all have an individual startup time anyways, so you *might* shorten the time, but still have the same problems.

You can counter any problem by making your tomcat available to the outside world only when it has fully been started up (e.g. through proper loadbalancer configuration). If your applications take too long to inintialize, you might want to work on this issue as well.